# current date as date object

Tags: php, wordpress

I am tryng to take away current date from a date stored in db of wordpress but it is a string i am finding hard to understand how to make a date object so i can do diff of it like this.

```
$dateJoined=the_field('date_joined', $post_id );
$dateJoined=the_field('expirey_date', $post_id );
$currentDate =  new DateTime(date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time())0;
$dateJoined = new DateTime($dateJoined);
$expiredate = new DateTime($expiredate);
```

I want to take the date from current date and get the number of days till their option will expire

```
$diff = $currentDate->diff($expiredate);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the current date, just use [`new DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php), you don't need to use arguments in the constructor.

If you want to create a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object from a string and you know the format, use the [`createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method.

```
$dateJoined = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", "06/02/2016");
$dateExpired = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", "06/10/2016");
```

To get the days between two dates you use the `diff` method as you said in the first post.

```
$diff = $dateJoined->diff($dateExpired);
echo $diff->days; // 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code

```
$dateJoined=the_field('date_joined', $post_id );
$expiredate=the_field('expirey_date', $post_id );
$dateJoined = date("m/d/y", strtotime($dateJoined));
$expiredate = date("m/d/y", strtotime($expiredate));
$currentDate =  date("d-m-Y");
$dateJoined = strtotime($dateJoined);
$expiredate = strtotime($expiredate);
$diff = date_diff($currentDate, $expiredate);
```

it will help you

Comment: its still giving me zero days when my two dates are 06/15/2016 05:03:40 and todays date so it should be giving me 13 days left ?.